# Test for a specific item with a unique name in a chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have looked at several questions that are close, but I still cannot get this. One question talks about checking a chest for any item, but I need to test for a specific item with a unique name.

I'm creating a quest. The player needs to bring back an Apple with the name "InnKeeper Apple".

I have tried this, but it is not working.

```
/testforblock 7652 62 744 minecraft:chest -1 {Item:{id:minecraft:apple,tag:{display:{Lore:["InnKeeper Apple"]}}}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm running a hosted server on spigot 1.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chests use an `Items` list to store their items. Lists surround their data with square brackets, and the data stored in this case are compounds (which surrounds data with curly brackets).

```
/testforblock 7652 62 744 minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{id:minecraft:apple,tag:{display:{Lore:["InnKeeper Apple"]}}}]}
```

Comment: I just tried it and I get an error...... [14:15:43] The block at 7652,62,744 did not have the required NBT keys.

Comment: I tried added ,slot:0b ,Count:64b but still get the same error

Comment: Its a regular chest and not a trapped chest

Comment: @ScottUSA The command works in vanilla. Mods very rarely mix well with command mechanics. I can't say if there is any solution at all with Spigot.

Comment: Hmmm, .... I just tried it it 1.9.4/vanilla (single player) and not working.  Getting the same error.   I copied and pasted the command exactly, but changed the coordinates.

Comment: And there is a correct apple in the chest? For example, this `/give` command allows it to work for me: `/give @p apple 1 0 {display:{Lore:["InnKeeper Apple"]}}`

Comment: I renamed a regular apple with the anvil.   I double checked the name.   checking again.   ... I see a difference... checking  command again.

Comment: Yep, it works in vanilla, but not in multiplayer spigot 1.9.4   :(